# Mysql return Count of all status for all departments Return 0 if null

Tags: mysql

Good Day,

I am having trouble generating a mysql query wherein I would like to list all the status and return the correspondin number of response for all departments. Here is what I've tried:

```
SELECT Status,Dept,Sum(Case when Status !="" Then 1 else 0 end) as Count
FROM result 
GROUP BY  Status,Dept
ORDER BY Status desc
```

But it returns only the status where there are existing records under that department . I would like to have a result that returns 0 if the department doesn't contain any records under the status.

Current Result

```
+------+--------+-------+
| Dept | Status | Count |
+------+--------+-------+
| a    | Neg    |     2 |
| b    | Neg    |     3 |
| c    | Neg    |     6 |
| a    | Pos    |     1 |
| b    | Pos    |     2 |
+------+--------+-------+
```

desired result:

```
+------+--------+-------+
| Dept | Status | Count |
+------+--------+-------+
| a    | Neg    |     2 |
| b    | Neg    |     3 |
| c    | Neg    |     6 |
| a    | Pos    |     1 |
| b    | Pos    |     2 |
| c    | POS    |     0 |
+------+--------+-------+
```

Here is the sqlfiddle link:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a24835/3

Comment: i never can understand SQL code that is rewitten als a one liner... Besides we need example data (place it on http://www.sqlfiddle.com) we can work with..Reverse engineering a one liner SQL with some resultsets without example data too a working SQL code is almost impossible to do.

Comment: Sorry , I'll edit my post . Thank you

Comment: But looking into your desired result and some parts in the online liner SQL.. i would think you need to use `LEFT JOIN` instead.

Comment: You only need the first subquery. The JOIN makes no sense.

Comment: Do you have a status table

Comment: no I dont have it is all in a single table

Comment: You need a cross join between all deps and status (all possible combinations of `dept, status`). In best case you would hold them in separate tables (`depts` and `status`). Alternatively you can cross join two `SELECT DISTINCT ..` subqueries:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a24835/57

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

DEMO: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a24835/54

```
select a.dept,a.status,
       case when b.cnt is null then 0
        else b.cnt end count
from
(select dept,status from
(select dept from result group by dept) i cross join
(select status from result group by status) j) a left join 
(select dept,status,count(1) cnt 
  from result group by dept,status) b
on a.status = b.status and a.dept=b.dept
```

Comment: Hi @KKK I dont think it solved my problem it outputs the same result as to my previous query

Comment: Did you run the code,  the first query will return the all combination of dept and status, then joining with other sub query to get the count.

Comment: Yeah I did run it.

Comment: Sorry man,I tried to run it on the sqlfiddle but the result still is the same

Comment: I have updated the answer, also on sqlfiddle, chck out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171868/discussion-between-kkk-and-kkk).